# How to define raised buttons into Material ExpansionPanel?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

How to define **Save** and **Cancel** buttons raised into *Material ExpansionPanel*?

Below the example in [AngularDart Gallery](https://dart-lang.github.io/angular_components/) :

[image]

I am looking for the behaviour like *Material Button*:

[image]

I didn't find mixins to apply this behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I put this as a separate answer, because you can't really put code in notes, but it is just a clarification from the first answer.

You shouldn't need the first ::ng-deep unless you want all material-expansionpanels in your app to have raised buttons.

This should work:

```
@import 'package:angular_components/material_button/mixins';

material-expansionpanel{
  @include raised-button('material-button')
}
```

Also anything that can be done only in CSS we try to leave it that way as forwarding inputs adds extra unneeded code weight. I'd even love to remove the raised input from button it shouldn't be needed, and just causes extra codesize, but changing it now isn't worth the work as we have a lot of code relying on it.

Comment: It works, thanks. Just a clarification on "forwarding inputs": should we use CSS instead of mixins?

Comment: Sorry I don’t understand mixins are CSS at the end of the day. If you are asking if you should us ::ng-deep to style the common components? I’d avoid it as we keep the mixins up to date.

Comment: Sorry.  I did not make myself clear in the question.  When you say "forwarding inputs adds extra unneeded code weight" what exactly does this extra code generate?  The use of :: ng-deep, the use of raised attribute, or the use of mixins?

Comment: Placing an `@Input` on the parent to get a value to set an `@Input` on the child and so on and so forth adds dart code in the component, in the generated template, and generates change detection all of which is run at runtime which is more expensive than throwing in some more CSS.

Answer (score 0):

```dart
@import 'package:angular_components/material_button/mixins';

::ng-deep material-expansionpanel{
  @include raised-button('material-button')
}
```

They didn't expose the `raised` input all the way up, so you have to select the buttons with `::ng-deep`. Be careful though, narrow your selectors to make sure you are targeting only the buttons you want raised.